# Promises: why is the resolve executed after sync code and before async one

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
const doWorkPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('#2 (async call)');
    }, 0);
    resolve('#3 (async call?)');
    console.log('#1 (sync call)');
});

doWorkPromise.then((result) => {
    console.log('Success!', result);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error!', error);
});
```

The output is:

> #1 (sync call)
> Success! #3 (async call?)
> #2 (async call)

I know that sync code lands on the call stack and the async code registers event-callback pair at the Node APIs, where the callback is moved to the callback queue after the event. The event loop is then going to take elements out of the callback queue only when the call stack is empty. Therefore, I expected to have the sync code executed first and then the async one in order, because the timeouts are 0s, like:

> #1 (sync call)
> #2 (async call)
> Success! #3 (async call?)

Can someone please explain why `resolve` is executed before '#2 (async call)'?

Comment: You can probably remove some some lines from your question to make it more succinct ! It looks like it's only about the order of 2 things, so removing the irrelevant makes this easier most likely.

Comment: Why do you ask about `reject`? It is never called...

Comment: why reject? you are not handling reject at all

Comment: sorry guys, It was a remainder from the first version!

Comment: @trincot The console.log is concatenating "Success" with the result from the resolve call

Comment: Indeed, I was too quick with that comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reject` is never executed.

`resolved` is executed before #2 because:

1. `setTimeout` puts a function on the time out queue
2. `resolve` resolves the promise
3. `console.log` logs #1
4. The function finished
5. `doWorkPromise.then` assigns a function to run when the promise resolves
6. The promise is already resolved so that function is executed
7. After the minimum timeout time passes the function passed to `setTimeout` is called and logs #2

Answer (score 0):

Your code executes the following *synchronously*:

```
resolve('#3 (async call?)');
```

...so that promise gets immediately in a resolved state. The fact that you have started a timer, as no bearing on the promise... it is unrelated.

So the `then` callback on that promise will be triggered on the next processing of the job queue, and so you'll see "Success", right after the execution of the main, synchronous code has completed.

Somewhat later (yes, even `setTimeout(..., 0)` will introduce a small delay), the timer will expire, but that event has **nothing** to do with any promise.

### The common pattern

When you create a promise with `new Promise` and want it to resolve some time later, then you could indeed use `setTimeout`, but then the idea is to call `resolve` only when that timer has expired. Otherwise the timer does not do anything that serves the promise:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    resolve();
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. I used setTimeout only to introduce some asynchronous execution. But if reject is synchronous, then why does '#1 (sync call)' print first. I think I didn't get that part.

Comment: I don't understand why you mention `reject`... you never call it. But `#1` prints first because the callback that you provide to `new Promise` is executed synchronously (immediately before continuing with code below `new Promise`), and (maybe that you misunderstand) `setTimeout` does not stop execution. It only schedules the execution of a callback, but execution goes immediately on with executing `resolve`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got the whole picture from @Quentin. Cannot upvote yet, otherwise I would!

Comment: So where was your misunderstanding if I may ask?

Comment: I oversaw the fact that the result from resolve will be printed when 'then' is executed :D The promise was already resolved, just the printing happens later.

Comment: But why did you think that `#2` would have come before "Success"?

Comment: I couldn't explain myself the order of execution and I started thinking that the resolve call is asynchronous. In that case setTimeout will be put to wait for its event to finish and resolve after it. setTimeout will finish immediately and print, then resolve will.